# How to get Array of failed deletes from elastic search( _delete_by_query)

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

Trying to delete decuments by _delete_by_query in elastic search

```
curl -XPOST -d '{"query":{"terms":{"pro_id":["p1","p2","p3"]}}}' 'localhost:8899/my_index/_delete_by_query'
```

get response like

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 0,
    "deleted": 1,
    "batches": 0,
    "version_conflicts": 0,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1.0,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": []
}
```

We are passing 3 Product ids only one gets deleted because p2 and p3 is not existed.So want to get failed ids(not exist) in failures[]. Is there any way to get failed ids in array ?

Comment: This is not a failed case. `_delete_by_query` deletes a document which matches the query. Not getting a document that matches the query cannot be considered as fail. You should use delete by document id. Use bulk API to delete multiple document ids in a single request.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant Thanks, But in bulk api , we can delete by only _id, How we can delete by another field in bulk?

Comment: No you can not delete by another field using bulk API